# How to install Charisma Bundle in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, charisma

There is a bundle called charisma for Laravel 3 but I want to use it with Laravel 4. Laravel 4 uses composer packages instead of bundles. Is there a package or a way to use charisma in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creator of Charisma here.

I have not created a package for Laravel 4 yet, by the way its just an HTML UI, so you can download and create you own Laravel HTML layout. http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/

Comment: Looks like a great pacakage. Are you planning on adding composor support?

Comment: Did you created a package for Laravel 4?

Comment: @RNKushwaha sorry, but L4's Composer based eco-system has made it irrelevant.

Comment: Can't understand. I am trying to learn larvel. It means it cannot be used in L4?

Comment: @RNKushwaha Of course you can use, its just HTML, use it anywhere. But a package for L4 isn't making enough sense.